# Foreach through different objects but all implement same interface possible?

Tags: java

Suppose I have this

```
interface Movable
{//some stuff}
```

And I have

```
class Car implements Movable
{//some stuff}
```

And also maybe I have

```
class Bike implements Movable
{//some stuff}
```

I noticed that if I had this:

```
ArrayList<Movable> movableThings = new ArrayList<Movable>();
movableThings.add(some kind of Car)
movableThings.add(some kind of Bike)
movableThings.add(some kind of Bike)
```

This can be called:

```
for(Movable m: movableThings)
```

But if I call this I get incompatible types:

```
for(Bike b: movableThings)
```

Can someone explain, and maybe offer a better way? 
I know I can use foreach Movable m: movableThings and then use instanceof to check for Bikes but is there another way?

**Edit:** alright thanks for clarifying guys... so I guess I either use instanceof or redesign my game

Answer (score 10):

I would not recommend using `instanceof`. The whole **point** of two types implementing a common interface is that, when using the interface, consumer code shouldn't be concerned with the specific implementation. I tend to get very suspicious when I see `instanceof` outside of `equals()`.

Use polymorphic dispatch instead of `instanceof` if you want different behaviors from different implementations:

```
interface Movable
{
    void move();
}

class Bike implements Movable
{
    public void move()
    {
        // bike-specific implementation of how to move
    }
}

class Car implements Movable
{
    public void move()
    {
        // car-specific implementation of how to move
    }
}
```

The implementation-specific method will be called on each type:

```
for (Movable m : movableThings)
{
    m.move();
}
```

If you only want to iterate over `Bike` types, create a collection that only consists of `Bike`s:

```
List<Bike> bikes = new ArrayList<Bike>();
// etc...

for (Bike bike : bikes)
{
    // do stuff with bikes
}
```

**N.B.** You should almost always declare the collection as a `List` (an interface) rather than an `ArrayList` (an implementation of the interface).

#### See also

- [Avoiding instanceof in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2790144/avoiding-instanceof-in-java)
- [Avoiding instanceof when checking a message type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253043/avoiding-instanceof-when-checking-a-message-type)
- [How does one use polymorphism instead of instanceof? (And why?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4192837/how-does-one-use-polymorphism-instead-of-instanceof-and-why)
- [Avoiding 'instanceof' in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6157835/avoiding-instanceof-in-java)
- [when should we use instanceof and when not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3776862/when-should-we-use-instanceof-and-when-not)

If you haven't already, you might also want to read though [The Java Tutorials: Interfaces and Inheritance](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/index.html).

Comment: +1 yes, of course you are right. @some Java amateur the common methods of derived classes should be put in the interface.

Answer (score 2):

You do need to use `instanceof`.  You may want to write a filter function to make it reusable.

That being said, this is probably a case where you want to use inheritance to allow the same method to be called on both classes in the same way.

Comment: that is unfortunate...
I didnt want to resort to instanceof because I have nested foreach loops and nested ifs inside those nested foreach loops will make it loop quite messy
well thanks for the confirmation

Comment: @someJavaamateur, do you mind posting a little bit more of what would be in that `//somestuff` section?  Maybe there is a better way, altogether.

Comment: The second sentence nails it - that's the whole _point_ of the two types implementing a common interface.

Answer (score 2):

Because your ArrayList is defined to be

```
 ArrayList<Movable>
```

the the get method of your ArrayList will return a type Movable. You need to cast it manually if you are sure about the runtime type (use instanceof to check it).

```
for(Movable m: movableThings){
      if (m instanceof Car){
            Car car = (Car)m;
      }
}
```

Comment: That is a strong code smell, however. If you only want to work with Bikes, this is not the right way to do it.

Comment: I think he is using an ArrayList<Movable> to store both Bikes, Car and so on.

Comment: Yes my arraylist of movable things has both bikes and cars
because at some point i use foreach(moveable m: movableThings) to call m.move()

Comment: @Matt Ball: Could you explain me a better solution, if ArrayList<Movable> stores both Bikes and Car?

Comment: unfortunately the arraylist is continuously changing; things get removed and added all the time so creating a new list isn't really a good idea but thanks

Comment: @some is the `move()` method defined in the `Movable` interface? If not, **it should be.**

Comment: it is defined in the interface
however, sometimes i might want to call move for only bikes from the list

Comment: @some that definitely hints at a design problem. If you need to be able to control bikes moving separately from cars, **use two separate lists.**

Comment: alright let me clarify, I might have a design problem/
the Movable interface also includes a draw function
and in a Loop in the game/
sometimes only certain things are moved/
but everything is always drawn/
because of double buffering/
hm... I'll think about using separate lists

Answer (score 0):

This is where [Google Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) or a similar collection library can be really beneficial.  You'll find tons of other uses for it so it's not a hard thing to justify including in your project.

In Guava:

```
for (Bike bike : Iterables.filter(movableThings, Bike.class) ) {
    //now you only have bikes
}
```